# How to store a blog post in a database

Tags: php, mysql

How to store a blog post in a database?

I suppose, that first I have to distinguish the paragraphs from the titles in the database. What is the right way to do that?

In the database?:

```
paragraph 1
title
paragraph 2
```

To be able to echo in html:

```
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<h2>title</h2>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
```

Comment: How would you know what is a title (and what kind...) and what is a paragraph? Seems pretty much impossible to me.

Comment: @yes, that is what I ask. How to store a blog post in a database and then echo in a html page

Comment: what about store the title and the paragraphs apart?

Comment: @Federico. Technically this is possible. But would you store your posts that way?

Comment: To answer your modified question: You would need to store html or something like markdown in the database to begin with and then you can get it out, transform it to html and display it. What you have in the database right now is useless.

Comment: Separate your data, title as a column, content as a column. For content use `nl2br`; or have users use a WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should store the text in your database in some formatted way. Otherwise you have no way to distinguish between headers and paragraphs.

As an example: think about how this website (stackoverflow.com) does it. You typed your question in some format (bold-> surround by two *-symbols, code->indent by 4 spaces, header->some other way, ...). This format can be easily translated to html using those regexes..

Comment: It's called `markdown` (what SO is using...) and there are libraries available to convert it back to html.

Comment: Can I use anything? there is no rules? for instance can I just put asterisk before and after a title in the database?

Comment: Yes you can use anything, limited by your php/regex programming skills of course ;) But as @jeroen points out, using the markdown language instead of inventing your own might be better because php libraries already exist to convert markdown to html (https://github.com/erusev/parsedown) so you don't have to write the code yourself.

Comment: sorry, I am a beginner. I still do no understand how to mark a sentence in the database that will be a h2 when I output to html. What says here cannot be applied, I think: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown

Comment: You can mark the text any way you like. But you will then need to write your own preg_replace regular expressions to change your markings with html tags. Now.. regular expressions are hard and it happens that people have already solved the problem of marking text and converting it to html. It is called markdown and there is PHP code available to convert a markdown string to a html string with no effort

Answer (score 2):

A good option is to store the text in Markdown. Markdown is a language created by John Gruber. Here are the rules:  http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax

In the example I give this is the solution:

```
# title 

paragraph 1

## subtitle

paragraph 2
```